# JUnit testing with a call to another class

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am currently trying to create a JUnit Test with a call to another class. I have worked every which way I know how and I can't seem to get it right. The GetHistory test is the one that is causing all my headaches. Any help or tips would be great!

```java
package medical.com.medicalApplication.model;
/**
 * 
 * 
 * This class represents a medical record model in the system
 *
 */
public class MedicalRecord {

    private Patient patient;
    private PatientHistory history;


    public MedicalRecord(Patient patient) {
        super();
        this.patient = patient;
        this.history = new PatientHistory();
    }

    public Patient getPatient() {
        return patient;
    }

    public PatientHistory getHistory() {
        return history;
    }   
}
```

And this is my current code:

```java
package medical.com.medicalApplication.model;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import medical.com.medicalApplication.model.PatientHistory;

public class MedicalRecordTest {

    @Test
    public void testGetPatient() {
        String patient = "Perez";
        Patient test = new Patient(patient, patient);
        assertTrue(test.getName().equals(patient));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetHistory() {
        String history = "Diabetic";
        PatientHistory test = new PatientHistory();
        assertTrue(test.getHistory.equals("Diabetic"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't forget to mention the exact problem you are experiencing (e.g. compilation error, failed assertion, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given all the other classes here. Also please format your code so your classes are show correctly.

Without the actual files, my best guess is  that these should return the instance of the class.

```
public Patient getPatient() {
    return this.patient;
}

public PatientHistory getHistory() {
    return this.history;
}
```

Additionally, you're testing wrong.

Your test should in this case should be using assertEquals:

```
assertEquals(patient.getFirstName(), medicalRecord.getPatient().getFirstName());
```

if you use assertTrue your error message will not be helpful. It will be:

```
expected false was true
```

if you use assertEquals your error message will be much more helpful. It will be

```
expected "perez" but was "abc"
```